# Regex lazy matching

Tags: regex, user-agent

I have this string

```
(Mozilla/5.0 \(X11; Linux x86_64\) AppleWebKit/537.36 \(KHTML, like Gecko\) Chrome/data Safari/data2) /Producer (Skia/PDF m80) /CreationDate (D:20200420090009+00'00') /ModDate (D:20200420090009+00'00')
```

I want to get the first ocurrence of () where there isn't any \ before ( or ). That case I would get

```
(Mozilla/5.0 \(X11; Linux x86_64\) AppleWebKit/537.36 \(KHTML, like Gecko\) Chrome/data Safari/data2)
```

I'm using this regex expression

```
\([\s\S]*[^\\]{1}\)?
```

However I get the whole string

Comment: In perl or in python? What have you tried? What did not work?

Comment: I'm processing the content of a PDF file. It has dictionaries. I have to save the keys/values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex can be broken down like so.

[The spaces and newlines are for clarity]

```
\(             match a literal (
  [\s\S]*      match 0 or more of whitespace or not-whitespace (anything)
  [^\\]{1}     match 1 thing which is not \
\)?            optionally match a literal )
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/e0YGZl/1)

It's that `[\s\S]*` which winds up slurping in everything.

The `?` on the end doesn't mean lazy, it makes matching the `)` optional. To be lazy, `?` must be put in front of an open-ended qualifier like `*?` or `+?` or `{3,}?` or `{1,5}?`.

---

To match just the first set of parenthesis, we want to lazily match anything between unescaped parens. Lazy matching anything is easy `.*?`.

Matching unescaped parens is a little harder. We could match `[^\\]\)`, but that requires a character to match. This won't work if the opening paren is at the beginning of the string because there's no character before the `(`. We can solve this by also matching the beginning of the string: `(?:[^\\]|^)\)`.

```
(?:           non-capturing group
  [^\\]         match a non \
  |             or
  ^             the beginning of the string
) 
\(            match a literal (
  .*?         lazy match 0 or more of anything
[^\\]         match a non \ 
\)            match a literal )
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/cI84qM/1)

But this will be foiled by `()`. [It will match all of `()(foo)`](https://regex101.com/r/cI84qM/2).

`(?:[^\\]|^)` matches the beginning of the string. `\(` matches the first `(`. That leaves `.*?[^\\]\)` looking at `)(foo)`. The first `)` does not match because there is no leading character, it was already consumed. So `.*?` gobbles up characters until it his `o)` which matches `[^\\]\)`.

The boundary problem is better solved by [negative look behinds](https://www.regextutorial.org/positive-and-negative-lookbehind-assertions.php). `(?<!\\)` says the preceding character must not be a `\` which includes no character at all. Lookbehinds don't consume what they match so they can be used to peek behind and ahead. Most, but not all, regex engines support them.

```
(?<!\\) \(    match a literal ( which is not after a \
  .*?         lazy match 0 or more of anything
(?<!\\) \)    match a literal ) which is not after a \
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/e0YGZl/2)

---

However, there are libraries to parse User-Agents. [ua-parser](https://github.com/ua-parser) has libraries for many languages,

Comment: Great explanation. This one ^((?:[^\\]|^)\(.*?[^\\]\))\s*([\s\S]*) is working. I can get the starting of the next key